# mount nfs correctly

Tags: permissions, mount, nfs, nas

I have purchased a WD-Ex2 NAS and am trying to share a folder via nfs with my ubuntu machine.

This folder will be used only by this machine and I want to be able to have execute permissions with my user. I would like it to be treated as one more home folder.

I am mounting the folder as follows

```
$ sudo cat /etc/fstab
...
#nfs mycloud
192.168.0.151:/nfs/tmp_msigs60 /media/tmp_msigs60  nfs     defaults,user,relatime,rw,exec    0       0
```

but I don't have execute permissions and the owner is user # 501
not my user

I have tried mounting with the following options

```
192.168.0.151:/nfs/tmp_msigs60 /media/tmp_msigs60  nfs     defaults,user,relatime,rw,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=002    0       0
```

but when putting `uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=002` I get the error:

```
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

Another thing I have tried is to edit `/etc/idmapd.conf` and change `nobody` and `nogroup` for my user, but I have not had any result either

```
[General]

Verbosity = 0
Pipefs-Directory = /run/rpc_pipefs


[Mapping]
Nobody-User = rodrigo
Nobody-Group = rodrigo
```

Another thing that I have noticed is that the speed of writing and reading starts with high speed, but it decreases considerably while transferring the file in that folder

Comment: Why NFS? Do you have some special need that requires this?

Comment: I just want to share this folder with Ubuntu and use it as another filesystem folder.  According to the internet this fits more to nfs than samba

Comment: Do not know what it is you read I use and most do Samba for that. NFS is a very old and as far as I know much slower protocol for that.

Comment: If you search for nfs vs samba all the results seem to agree that nfs is a bit faster if both systems are linux.  On the other hand with samba the permission of the files is a bit strange, the files remain with the permissions that are mounted and I cannot change them, for example all files have execution permission.